# WebStorm Equivalent of ///<reference/>?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, webstorm

In Visual Studio, you can include comments like this:

```
/// <reference path="<path to javascript file>" />
```

And then it adds types from those files to Intellisense. How do I do this in WebStorm?

More specifically, I want to add JavaScript autocompletion for Vue.js.

Answer (score 1):

there are no comments like this in WebStorm (`/// <reference path>` comments are supported for referencing Typescript namespaces, but not used for JavaScript types resolving). Completion list is based on JavaScript index, WebStorm takes all JavaScript files in the project and goes through them, adding functions and methods to it. The index is automatically updated whenever existing files are changed or new files are added.